# Mapping numerical values to characters

Tags: visual-c++

Using C++, I am attempting to write a program that encrypts a string. I have to map each letter of the alphabet to a numerical value: for example, a = 0, b = 1, c = 2 and so on. So far, I have created a void function that takes a string as a parameter and uses a switch statement to output the values. The problem is, the values are chars, not ints and I can't use the math operators to alter them. 
My source code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void mapped_string(string in)
{   string mapped_string;
    int length = in.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {   
        switch (in[i])
        {
        case 'a':
            cout<<"0";
            break;
        case 'b':
            cout<<"1";
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout<<"2";
            break;
        case 'd':
            cout<<"3";
            break;
        case 'e':
            cout<<"4";
            break;
        case 'f':
            cout<<"5";
            break;
        case 'g':
            cout<<"6";
            break;
        case 'h':
            cout<<"7";
            break;
        case 'i':
            cout<<"8";
            break;
        case 'j':
            cout<<"9";
            break;
        case 'k':
            cout<<"10";
            break;
        case 'l':
            cout<<"11";
            break;
        case 'm':
            cout<<"12";
            break;
        case 'n':
            cout<<"13";
            break;
        case 'o':
            cout<<"14";
            break;
        case 'p':
            cout<<"15";
            break;
        case 'q':
            cout<<"16";
            break;
        case 'r':
            cout<<"17";
            break;
        case 's':
            cout<<"18";
            break;
        case 't':
            cout<<"19";
            break;

        default:
            cout<< in[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   string str1 = "Hello";

    mapped_string(str1);



        cout    << "Press any key to exit." << endl;
        cin.ignore(2);
        return 0;
}
```

I need this function to map each char in the string to a int value and store the int values in a new string called mapped_string.

Answer (score 0):

```
//stringstream is used as string 'builder'.
std::stringstream storedstr;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{   
    //As op's code but without the lengthy switch statement. Just cast to get an int.
    int intEquiv = (int)(in[i]);
    if (in[i] > 'z' || in[i] < 'a') intEquiv = (int)(in[i]) - 'a'
    storedstr << intEquiv;

    //Show what we are adding, like in original loop;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << intEquiv;
    std::cout << ss.str();
}
mapped_string = storedstr.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Chars in C/C++ have numeric values, ASCII format, 'A' is 65, 'B' is 66 ... 'a' is 97, 'b' is 98 and so forth, as such you can apply mathematical operators on them,  it may be easier to simply stick to the well known ASCII format, instead of creating your own, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

```
string str1 = "Hello";
for (int index = 0; index < str1.length(); index++)
    cout << "char: " << str1[index] << " ascii numeric values: " << (int)(str1[index]) << endl;
```

prints:

```
char: H ascii numeric values: 72
char: e ascii numeric values: 101
char: l ascii numeric values: 108
char: l ascii numeric values: 108
char: o ascii numeric values: 111
```

a simple/naive encryption scheme would be to simply shift the chars by certain amount (shift cypher), though when working with encryption schemes you should always be careful of overflows, depending on the scheme your are implementing.

```
  string str1 = "Hello", cipher = "";    
  for (int index = 0; index < str1.length(); index++)
      cipher += (char)(str1[index] + 10);
  cout << "original: " << str1 << " cipher " << cipher << endl;
```

prints:

```
 original: Hello cipher Rovvy
```

to get back the original simply subtract the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string mapped_string(string in, char password)
{
    transform(in.begin(), in.end(), in.begin(), [password](char& x){ return x ^ password; });
    return in;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char password = '1';
    string str1 = "Hello";
    string str2 = mapped_string(str1, password); // encrypt str1
    string str3 = mapped_string(str2, password); // decrypt str2
    cout << "Original: " << str1 << endl;
    cout << "Encrypt:  " << str2 << endl;
    cout << "Decrypt:  " << str3 << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
Original: Hello
Encrypt:  yT]]
Decrypt:  Hello